# How can I use speech recognition to perform a web search

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

What I want is that when I ask my program to open chrome, it asks me what I want.

Search and I say what I want to search and it searches it, but I'm having some issues and I cant find much online either.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine reg = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = "12345".ToString().Replace("123", "");
            s.Speak("booting up");
            s.Speak("AID online");
            s.Speak("Hello sir, how may i assist you?");
            string[] commands = { "hello AID", "what are you", "how are you", "what's the time", "open music", "sing me a song", "thank you AID", "what does AID mean", "Tell me a joke", "i need to take notes", "i want to search the web" };
            reg.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            reg.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(commands))));
            reg.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            reg.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec);

        }

        public string time()
        {
            DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
            string o = n.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
            return o;
        }

        public void rec(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs x)
        {

            string recString = x.Result.Text;
            switch(recString)
            {
                case "hello AID":
                    s.Speak("Hello sir");
                    break;
                case "how are you":
                    s.Speak("I'm good, how are you?");
                    break;
                case "what's the time":
                    s.Speak(time());
                    break;
                case "open music":
                    s.Speak("on it sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wmplayer.exe");
                    break;
                case "sing me a song":
                    s.Speak("im a little tea pot short and stout here is my handle here is my spout if you poor me over hear me shout tip me up and poor me out");
                    break;
                case "thank you AID":
                    s.Speak("you are very welcome sir ");
                    break;
                case "what are you":
                    s.Speak("I am AID");
                    break;
                case "what does AID mean":
                    s.Speak("Aid means assistance and intelligent device");
                    break;
                case "Tell me a joke":
                    s.Speak("I like my relationships like I like my source, open");
                    break;
                case "i need to take notes":
                    s.Speak("opening notepad now sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                    break;
                case "i want to search the web":
                    s.Speak("opening the web now sir");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a function where I say I want to search the web it starts chrome but I want to be able to search using voice.

For example:

- I want to search the web
- What do you wish to search

Then it would search for what I have asked it to search.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Speech API provides Speech recognition capabilities:

http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/speech

And there are examples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Speech-Recognition-19c452b4

Bing Speech Recognition Control web search sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Speech-Recognition-210c8978

Voice Translator Sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Voice-Translator-Sample-59be8627